# Why isalpha() doesn't recognize a letter in a string?

Tags: python, string, isalpha

I am new in python and I am having some problems with the isaplha() function. I would like to check whether in a variable some of the characters are letters. I have implemented a for loop that goes through all the character and check whether they are letters or not.

```
variable = '23 Uhr'
for character in variable:           
    is_letter = variable.isalpha()  
    print(character, is_letter)
```

The problem is that it doesn't distinguish between letters and digits and gives me 'False' as output for every character (even if it is actually a letter!). I have also tried to use the isdigit() function to verify whether it can distinguish numbers, but also in this case it always returns me 'False'. I think it is a problem that has to do with how the variable is stored. The value that I am using, indeed, is part of a bigger dataframe, but when I use the type() function, it tells me that is a part of the class string. I don't know how to solve the problem.
Thank you !

Comment: You mean, `character.isalpha()`, not `variable.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical error on your code. Instead of

```
is_letter = variable.isalpha()
```

it should be

```
is_letter = character.isalpha()
```

Working code:

```
>>> variable = '23 Uhr'
>>> for character in variable:
...     is_letter = character.isalpha()
...     print(character, is_letter)
... 
2 False
3 False
  False
U True
h True
r True
```